# How to create responsive boxes with even margins inside a centered parent div

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to have 4 or more boxes inside a parent with even margins that have percentage based width and heights.

Below is what I currently have.

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h3>box 1</h3>
    <h3>box 2</h3>
    <h3 class="clear1">box 3</h3>
    <h3>box 4</h3>
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS Styles**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #ccddff;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ffcccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 300px;
  }

h3 {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1%;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

.clear1 {
  clear: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you 're asking is for the elements to have the same distance from the container, as they have from each other.
Since you only want 2 elements on each row with a margin of 1% each, you can just add a padding of .5% on the container element. For 4 elements on each row with margin 1%, you should set the padding to .25%.

You should also use divs to contain the row elements, instead of using a class on the first element of each row.

Answer (score 1):

Playing around with media queries you can do this.

**1 - Add media-query:**

```
@media (max-width: 780px) { 
  h3 {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

"While width is less than 780px, h3 will have this classes"

**2 - You will have problems with the margin in the container, i would add padding to the container instead of using margin in the boxes inside.**

If you want more responsive sizes, just play with the media-query.

Finished codepen: https://codepen.io/bitxelus/pen/awNNPG

Comment: Thanks for the comment. How would you get a gap in-between the inside boxes without the margin?

Comment: Why without margin? It is the best way to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

If you mean responsive i think you should consider using javascript to set the widths and margin so they can be precise and adjust with the parent
Still you can adjust your code like:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h3>box 1</h3>
    <h3>box 2</h3>
    <h3 class="clear1">box 3</h3>
    <h3>box 4</h3>
  </div>
</body>

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #ccddff;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ffcccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 300px;
  }

h3 {
  float: left;
  width: 24%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1%;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

.clear1 {
  clear: left;
}
```

i Changed your h3 width to 24% considering the fact that there's four boxes in the parent tag and been floated you have to divide the 100% width of the parent by 4 and also remove 1% for each margin so the element maintain a grid position in the parent container